# Standard Deviation Question multiplying data set by a constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

Suppose that the $25$ numbers in data set $S$ have mean $7$ and standard deviation
$3$. If each of the numbers in $S$ is multiplied by $4$ to form a new data set $T$, what is
the standard deviation of $T$?

Would not the answer be $12$, because the book's answer is $6$? The explanation for the book answers uses the wrong formula for standard deviation,taking the difference of the new data points minus the new mean instead of the difference squared.

Comment: I thought it was always the case that multiplying a set of data by a constant would also multiply the standard deviation by the absolute value of the constant. But the book has the answer $6$, whereas I got the answer $12$. So is the book correct, and do I need to try this problem again?

Comment: The standard deviation [scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Identities_and_mathematical_properties) directly with the scale of the random variable

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of a data set, then the standard deviation becomes $k\sigma$ if each number in the data set is multiplied by $k$. In this case the standard deviation becomes $$3\times 4=12$$

Comment: Ok so the book I was using is wrong